# How can I request a external website with my data in observer and get back the response?

Tags: event-observer

Actually am getting my total amount of product in Observer of event

> sales_order_invoice_save_after

Now I need to place this amount in a url and access the particular url and get back the response. How can be it done?

And also in this observer how can i get the product attribute values?

```
$observer->getEvent()->getInvoice()->getOrder() -> getData();
```

By the above code am getting the order details, but i need to get the product details.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Observer function could look something like below.

```
$orderItems = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice()->getOrder()->getAllItems();
 $ch = curl_init();
 $url = <YOUR URL >

foreach($orderItems as $item)
{
    $product = $item->getProduct();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); // remove body
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $head = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);


}

curl_close($ch);
```

Then do a curl request  to the external website: [READ here:](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php)

Comment: Thanks @Parassood. But when am trying with this code am getting error as Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING over here curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

Comment: Have you put in your own URL in $url?

Comment: Thanks a lot @parassood the code is working properly, it was simple mistake from my side.

Comment: Hello @parassood can you help me in getting the product  custom attribute values. Am getting all other attribute values in  $product = $item->getProduct(), but product custom attribute values are not getting, Thanks .

Comment: Please post that as a separate question and I am sure someone will help you.